# Manipulating browser (window) size using Splinter

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation, splinter

I am trying to use the Firefox driver for [Splinter](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter) to test some responsive design.

Naturally, this requires me to resize the browser window. I can't find anything at all about browser resizing in [the documentation](https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

How can I do this?

```
from splinter import Browser
with Browser() as browser:
    # How do I set the browser size?
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just do this:

```
browser.driver.set_window_size(640, 480)
```

The Splinter API doesn't seem to directly support this - or at least not yet. The generic [API docs](https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html), as well as the docs for each specific browser's driver, currently make no mention of anything related to window size). However, a seemingly undocumented feature is that you're able to access the underlying Selenium webdriver instance of a Splinter webdriver instance through its `.driver` property:

```
>>> from splinter import Browser
>>> browser = Browser()
>>> browser
<splinter.driver.webdriver.firefox.WebDriver object at 0x7fac66d93a10>
>>> browser.driver
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver object at 0x1fbf3d0>
```

This allows us to use any Selenium features that don't have wrappers in the Splinter API, like resizing the browser with the [`set_window_size` method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_window_size).

Comment: This (browser.driver.set_window_size(640, 480) is working perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: +1 for helping me find the driver under the browser.  maximize is what I was looking for and on firefox is browser.driver.maximize_window()